# filter RealmObject with NSPredicate not working

Tags: filter, realm, nspredicate

I have a very strange issue. I want to retrieve an object with a given id from realm. if I do:

```
Array(realm.objects(MyClass.self).filter(NSPredicate(format:"id == %d",id))).first
```

I get nil, no items.

But if I do:

```
Array(realm.objects(MyClass.self)).filter{$0.id == id}.first
```

I get the object!!

I would avoid to retrieve all the objects and then manually filter, I would use the filter method offered in RealmSwift. And this is the first time I have this issue!
Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use `%@` instead of `%d`. Secondly, there's no need to create an `NSPredicate` inside the `filter`, you can simply use predicate syntax there. There's also no need to convert the `Results` to an `Array`.

```
realm.objects(MyClass.self).filter("id == %@",id).first
```